# Fazer download de Ficheiro através de API + Lumen + Maatwebsite\Excel

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, angular, lumen

Tenho uma aplicação Angular 5 que faz uma requisição ao backend feito em Lumen 5.6, neste backend, tenho uma função que cria um ficheiro excel, com a biblioteca Maatwebsite\Excel, para download. 
No entanto não estou a conseguir fazer download do ficheiro através da API, caso crie uma rota que seja acessivel sem credenciais, através do browser consigo fazer download, mas pela API retorna-me uns caracteres esquisitos.

O que me retorna neste momento: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha requisição da API (Angula 5):

Função do angular

```
download(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.httpService.builder('/registrations/download').download()
        .then((res) => {
            let blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'text/csv' });
            let url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(url);
        });
}
```

Service do angular:

```
download() {
    let header: Headers;
    let token = this.getCookie('token');
    this.header = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Accept': 'application/csv', 'responseType': 'blob'});
    let observable = this.watch(this.http.get(this.url, {headers: this.header}));
    return this.toPromise(observable);
}
```

Lumen 5.6

```
public function downloadExcel(){
    $data = $this->model->all();
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
        'Accept' => 'application/csv',
        'responseType' => 'blob'
    ];
    $teste = Excel::create('Laravel Excel', function($excel)use($data) {
        $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) use ($data) {
            $header = array(
                        'ID',
                        'First Name',
                        'Last Name',                           

            );
            $sheet->fromArray(array($header), null, 'A1', false, false);

            foreach ($data as $row){                    
                $row = $row->toArray();
                $sheet->fromArray(array($row), null, 'A1', false, false);
            }
        });
    })->download('xls', $headers);

    return response()->download($teste, 'myfile.csv', [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename='myfile.csv'",
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Por favor indique a versão do Maatwebsite\Excel

Comment: 2.1, mas a biblioteca esta a funcionar correctamente, cria o ficheiro, porque se eu criar uma rota directa através do browser consigo criar e fazer download do ficheiro xls.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no primeiro parâmetro do método download.

```
->download('xls', $headers);
```

Você está dizendo pra biblioteca gerar um `xls`, enquanto em todo o restante do código você está usando CSV.

Voce pode trocar o `xls` por `csv` que irá trazer um arquivo csv para você. Pode também remover as ultimas 4 linhas da sua action.

```
 return response()->download($teste, 'myfile.csv', [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename='myfile.csv'",
]);
```

A biblioteca já seta esses valores quando voce chama o método `download` como voce pode ver [olhando o código.](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/b522845318f72e4e7dfeb101e48f9e9c3da445cf/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Writers/LaravelExcelWriter.php#L347)

Comment: Não funcionou, obrigado na mesma